# Can a druid use a (wooden) Wand of the War Mage as a focus?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, druid, spellcasting-focus

Could a Druid use a Wand of the War Mage as a Druidic focus, if the wand was made of wood?

Answer (score 10):

Probably. A druidic focus is defined as:

> A
>   druidic
>   focus
>   might
>   be
>   a
>   sprig
>   of
>   mistletoe
>   or
>   holly,
>   **a
>   wand
>   or
>   scepter
>   made
>   of
>   yew
>   or
>   another
>   special
>   wood**,
>   a
>   staff
>   drawn
>   whole
>   out
>   of
>   a
>   living
>   tree,
>   or
>   a
>   totem
>   object
>   incorporating
>   feathers,
>   fur,
>   bones,
>   and
>   teeth
>   from
>   sacred
>   animals.
>   A
>   druid
>   can
>   use
>   such
>   an
>   object
>   as
>   a
>   spellcasting
>   focus.

So, if the Wand of the War Mage is made from "yew or another special wood", then the Druid should be able to use it as a focus. The only requirement the Wand of the War Mage itself has is that it requires attunement by a spellcaster. A Druid is a spellcaster, so this isn't a problem. As long as it's made of the right wood, the Druid should be able to use it, and get its bonuses.